# DNS and IP settings

Tags: vpn, dns

I have a question regarding the settings for IP address and DNS servers. I use a VPN and also Heimdal Pro security. The problem is that Heimdal Pro doesn't allow customized settings for either. (127.0.0.1) is used instead, and my VPN wants to use (192.168.1.x) format for IP. So what happens is my internet connection constantly goes off and back on repeatedly. Is there a way to make these addresses be interchangable? Something like 127.0.0.1 would get forwarded to my computer IP and vice-versa? I'm looking for a way to continue with Heimdal Pro, but as of right now, its uninstalled and a shame to disregard it if there's a solution, even if it means doing manual extra steps. Thank you for any advice on this delimna.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a VPN solution in combination with Heimdal V2, our application doesn't understand this automatically and it needs a backdoor for Heimdal to bypass it. For this, we recommend configuring an exception in your VPN solution like in this guide:

https://support.heimdalsecurity.com/hc/en-us/articles/207385449-Using-Heimdal-with-Cisco-Anyconnect-VPN

If you still need further assistence, just contact us directly on our webpage.

Best regards,

Răzvan Crâznic - Ionuț
Senior Support Technician (English & German)

Heimdal Security A/S & Heimdal Security SRL
The Cyberthreat Security suite. We protect what other endpoint solutions can't

http://www.heimdalsecurity.com/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.